# ASP.NET VB Web app using azure authentication

Tags: asp.net

I have a basic website created using VB.NET. I need to add authentication and, as we use Azure Active Directory, I thought I could connect it to that.

All I need to do is be able to have the username of the current user, so I can then turn on or off buttons etc depending who they are.

All the examples I can find are for ASP.NET Web applications.

How do I add to a standard site?

Thanks

Gareth

Comment: I'm not sure I could help but out of curiosity, isn't ASP.NET Web Application the only way to build web applications with the .NET framework? You say your basic web site was created using VB.NET but that's the language and yet you can build ASP.NET Web Applications using VB.NET. So I don't understand what do you mean when you say that all examples you could find where for ASP.NET only. Those are the only things you will find and the only thing you will need for the issue you are having. That's because your VB.NET website is served through the ASP.NET underlying technology

Comment: Hi, thaks for the response. you are right, i made a mistake in my original post. It is written in ASP.NET, using VB. the only examples talk about web applications which looks to be different from web Sites??